# How to trim and concatenate strings in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, string, trim

I want an event which currently has its starting date and ending date in a list as:

```
Event1={Start: 'Sep 18, 2017 10:00AM', End: 'Sep 18, 2017 11:00AM'}
```

How can I trim and concatenate this to just display `Event1` as  `Sep 18, 2017, 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM` as my event start and end dates would always be the same so I don't need them to displayed separately.

I could do them both in my controller or `HTML` file, I believe.

Thanks

Comment: do events only take place in the same day?

Comment: I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415176/how-can-i-convert-date-to-a- readable-form-in-angular-and-also-concatenate-two-da

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in your controller:

`Event1 = Event1.Start + ' - ' + Event1.End.split(' ')[3];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure javascript for this simple trick.

```
var Event1={Start: 'Sep 18, 2017 10:00AM', End: 'Sep 18, 2017 11:00AM'}

var result= Event1.Start + ' - ' + Event1.End.split(' ')[3];
```

Output:

```
"Sep 18, 2017 10:00AM - 11:00AM"
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can write method as ***getTimeFromDate()*** below to get time when you
>   pass date to that method. You can call this method from Html or from controller itself as per your choice.

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the time as a string.</p>

<button onclick="getTimeFromDate('September 22, 2017 11:12:00')">Hit Me!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function getTimeFromDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date);
    var n = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To **concat** 2 string you can use `'+' operator` and to **trim** a part of a string you can use `substr()` function.

**Check below demo for your problem**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.title='Hello world';
var Event1={Start: 'Sep 18, 2017 10:00AM', End: 'Sep 18, 2017 11:00AM'};
 $scope.newDate=Event1.Start+' - '+Event1.End.substr(Event1.End.length-7);
 
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
    <div>{{newDate}}</div>
</div>
```