# How can I convert date to a readable form in Angular and also concatenate two dates?

Tags: string, date

For any event, Im getting dates in my html file in the following manner:

```
         Start Date: 2017-09-25T10:00:00 
         End Date:   2017-09-25T11:00:00
```

In my Controller I have them saved as :

```
         Event= {StartDate: start, EndDate: end}
```

I am looking for a way to output them in my html with some concatenation and trimming done to the date. My event date will always be the same so I would like to be displayed something like:

```
              September 09 2017, 10 AM - 11:00 AM
```

Help Needed!

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I am using Angular 1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working plunker that will give you a feel for the date formatting you're after: https://plnkr.co/edit/tmxQY9RyqGzHwCKhvQN0?p=preview

**The template interpolation is key here**

```
{{Event.StartDate | date:"MMMM dd yyyy ', ' h"}} {{Event.EndDate | date: "'-' h:mm a"}}
```

Note: you could save yourself from parsing the left side of the "-" with Angular's 'longDate', but that will add a comma after the day of the month (e.g. September 20, 2017 vs September 20 2017).

Check out the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for detailed info on which date parsing character does what.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Just use JavaScript, you have the split function (ex: `.split(/[-T]+/)`). For the month you have the 09 number, create your own function to get the month by array's indexes.